# Deploying VS2010 app with Crystal Reports dll not found on server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, crystal-reports-2008

I have created a small c# application that opens a crystal report, saves it to pdf, then emails it. Everything works great.

I tried to deploy this application to a server that has crystal runtime on it. But when I try to run my application on the server, it throws an error telling me it cannot find the dll reference. Sure enough, there are no dlls on the server.

I developed the application in VS2010 Express for CR2008. The error I get when I try to run it is

"Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeytoken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. the system cannot find the file specified."

I figured to solve this problem all I would need to do is reference the dlls on the server. But alas! The server has no dlls. It does have the assemblies, but not the dlls. The assemblies are version 12.0.1100.0, but I don't know how to fix version numbers in my application.

Is there a way to fix this? Sorry my question isn't more specific. I am hunting for options and information as much as I am hunting for a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you set 'copy local' in your project file | references? This should deploy dependencies when publishing.

Comment: Yes I did this. It added the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine and CrystalDecisions.Shared dlls to the project file itself. But I get the error I described above. When I tried manually adding a copy of the one above, I got another error: "Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly."

Comment: Have you tried installing the runtime crystal reports on the server? I mean the same version you are using?